# Calculate sum of datatable-columns and datatable-rows

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

```
column[0]    column[1]       column[2]    total-
==========   =========       =========    ======   
row[1]         1               2           3
row[2]         1               0           1
total          2               2           4
```

I only able to get value to calculate at column[0] but it wasn't start from column[1]. What did I miss out in this ?

```
  Dim totalrow = ExportDT.NewRow
  For Each col As Data.DataColumn In ExportDT.Columns
    For n_Loop As Integer = 1 To ExportDT.Columns.Count - 1
      Dim colname As Integer = col.ColumnName[n_loop]
      totalrow(col.ColumnName) = Convert.ToDouble(ExportDT.Compute("SUM(
                                                   " & colname & ")", "nothing"))
    Next
  Next
  ExportDT.Rows.Add(totalrow)
```

Here is my full script. Still I getting error and could not done any sum total in data table.

Dim objDB As New Database(AppSettings("datasource"), AppSettings("database"), AppSettings("username"), AppSettings("password"))
            Dim TempComplaintCatDT As New Data.DataTable
            Dim TempProjectDT As New Data.DataTable
            Dim TempComplaintDT As New Data.DataTable
            Dim ExportDT As New Data.DataTable

```
        objDB.OpenConnection()
        objDB.dbVariable.SQLString = "SELECT CategoryUID,Category FROM aw_complaintcat ORDER BY Category"
        objDB.FillData(TempComplaintCatDT, "ComplaintCat", Database.SQLCommandType.NormalString)

        objDB.dbVariable.SQLString = "SELECT DISTINCT NameOfProject FROM aw_complaint ORDER BY NameOfProject"
        objDB.FillData(TempProjectDT, "Projet", Database.SQLCommandType.NormalString)

        objDB.dbVariable.SQLString = "SELECT ComplaintCategory, NameOfProject FROM aw_complaint"
        objDB.FillData(TempComplaintDT, "Complaint", Database.SQLCommandType.NormalString)
        objDB.CloseConnection()

        'Using Excel for Generate the Report
        ExportDT.Columns.Add("Category")
        For Each ProjectRow As Data.DataRow In TempProjectDT.Rows
            ExportDT.Columns.Add(ProjectRow.Item("NameOfProject").ToString.Trim)

        Next
        Dim NewRow As Data.DataRow
        Dim ComplaintDV As New Data.DataView(TempComplaintDT)
        Dim totalrow = ExportDT.NewRow
        For Each CategoryRow As Data.DataRow In TempComplaintCatDT.Rows

            NewRow = ExportDT.NewRow
            'list all the category in table
            NewRow.Item("Category") = CategoryRow.Item("Category").ToString

            For nLoop As Integer = 1 To ExportDT.Columns.Count - 1
                'count the project receive complaint
                ComplaintDV.RowFilter = "ComplaintCategory='" & CategoryRow.Item("Category").ToString & "' AND NameOfProject='" & ExportDT.Columns(nLoop).ColumnName & "'"

                If ComplaintDV.Count > 0 Then
                    NewRow.Item(ExportDT.Columns(nLoop).ColumnName) = ComplaintDV.Count
                Else
                    NewRow.Item(ExportDT.Columns(nLoop).ColumnName) = "0"
                End If
            Next

            For Each col As Data.DataColumn In ExportDT.Columns

                For n_Loop As Integer = 0 To ExportDT.Columns.Count - 1
                    Dim colname As Integer = col.ColumnName

                    totalrow(col.ColumnName) = Convert.ToDouble(ExportDT.Compute("SUM(" & colname & ")", "ComplaintCategory=" & CategoryRow.Item("Category").ToString))
                Next
            Next
            ExportDT.Rows.Add(totalrow)
            ExportDT.Rows.Add(NewRow)
        Next

        ExportDT.Columns.Add("Total-")

        ExportDT.Rows.Add("Total")
```

Comment: Did you mean VBSCRIPT, or VB.NET? You wouldn't use VBSCRIPT most likely.

Comment: its beacuase you have given N_loop to start with 1 instead of 0 in for loop.change it to `For n_Loop As Integer = 0 To ExportDT.Columns.Count - 1`

Comment: I have change my loop to 0 but it still getting column[0]. I need to start the sum at column[1] till end.